# Apache Shindig API

Tags: apache-shindig

Is there a better api with lot of examples like jquery for shindig. I'm tired of searching. I could not find one proper site for examples at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, there is no such site like jquery where you can find out lots of examples. There are few examples for shindig. You can check the links.

https://cwiki.apache.org/SHINDIG/shindig-spring-example.html

http://code.google.com/p/partuza/updates/list

https://github.com/thesmith/bbc-shindig-example